# Use sed to replace string but avoid replacing when it is a substring

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I would like to perform string substitution in several files.

The string is particular as it is in the form  `use module_plotting`
and I need to avoid the replacement when encountering a string like `use module_plotting_debug`.

Thanks is advance for the answer(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundary expressions:

```
sed 's/\<use module_plotting\>/use module_plotting_debug/'
```

The zero-width patterns `\<` and `\>` will match on the boundaries of "words", i.e. between a non-word character and a word character with `\<` and between a word character and a non-word character with `\>`.

A "word character" is any alphanumeric character (possibly with taking the current locale into account, I'm uncertain about that).

My [`re_format(7)` manual](http://man.openbsd.org/re_format) says that  `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are supposed to be more portable, but these does not seem to work with GNU `sed` on my system.

Comment: (with `sed` implementations that support those `\<`/`\>` extensions. AFAIK, those come from `ex`/`vi`, but even on BSDs, they didn't make it to `sed` until decades later and are still not standard. Note that it would still match inside `use module_plotting-debug`)